# Flutter how to create package with function

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to make a package. I need to use async function, but I can't use it while building package.

Package Code:

```
class Sozluk {
  wiki(ceviri) async {
    var res = await http.Client()
          .get(Uri.parse('https://sozluk.gov.tr/gts?ara=$ceviri'));
      var body = res.body;
      var decoded = jsonDecode(body);
      var json = decoded[0];
      var sozlukanlam = json["anlamlarListe"][0]["anlam"];
      print(sozlukanlam);
      return sozlukanlam;
  }
}
```

Test Code:

```
void main() {
  test('köpek', () {
    final sozluk = Sozluk();
    var cevap = sozluk.wiki('köpek');
    print(cevap);
  });
}
```

The print I got:

```
Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is missing a lot of pieces. Dart is strongly typed, that is an *advantage*, please use it.

Problems:

- `ceviri` has no explicit type.
- `wiki` has no explicit return type.
- `wiki` is not `await`ed
- Your anonymous method is not `async`.

More information about `Future`s, `async` and `await`: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Fixing your code as good as possible:

```
class Sozluk {
  Future<TYPE_X> wiki(TYPE_Y ceviri) async {
    var res = await http.Client()
          .get(Uri.parse('https://sozluk.gov.tr/gts?ara=$ceviri'));
      var body = res.body;
      var decoded = jsonDecode(body);
      var json = decoded[0];
      var sozlukanlam = json["anlamlarListe"][0]["anlam"];
      print(sozlukanlam);
      return sozlukanlam;
  }
}
```

Test Code:

```
void main() {
  test('köpek', () async {
    final sozluk = Sozluk();
    var cevap = await sozluk.wiki('köpek');
    print(cevap);
  });
}
```

Please note that **you** need to fill in TYPE_X and TYPE_Y, I have no idea which datatypes best represent your data. Is it a number? A text? You decide.

Answer (score 0):

Yout question is unclear.

If you need to print

> sozlukanlam

var in test function you need to await your wiki function becaus it is async.

So you could do somthing like that:

```
void main() {
  test('köpek', () async {
    final sozluk = Sozluk();
    var cevap = await sozluk.wiki('köpek');
    print(cevap);
  });
}
```

OR, if test function couldn't bee async

```
void main() {
  test('köpek', () {
    final sozluk = Sozluk();
    sozluk.wiki('köpek').then((sozlukanlam)=>print(cevap));
  });
}
```